# Reactor, how to maintain application alive

Tags: spring, reactive, project-reactor

The sequence is asynchronous so this will immediately return control to the calling thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux<Long> tick = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    Flux<String> ticktock = tick.map(e -> e % 2 == 0 ? "tick" : "tock");
    ticktock
            .log()
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

What would be a correct way to maintain the program alive while the subscriber is consuming the infinite flow ?

Is there something inside the Project Reactor that does the job ? or should I resort to things like while(true) {} or Thread.sleep ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Hit 'Enter' to terminate");
System.in.read();
```

In the end of your `main()`. 
This way the program will be blocked until the keyboard interaction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I'm looking more for best practices related to the Reactor project. Otherwise with pure Java it's not a problem to block the main thread.

Comment: I think it's not Reactor responsibility to deal with these use-cases. More over it is really based on the standard Java as much as possible. You can use `CountDownLatch` for the same blocking reason. You can also take a look into the `StepVerifier` instead of `subscribe()` and check a several values before exiting.

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if there was some utility available inside Reactor to do that, not yet I guess ;) Thank you Artem !